# Javascript: Conditional include of a script in angularJS based webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My webapp (a Single page application) is based on `AngularJS`. The `index.html` page is structured like this:

```
<html>

<body ng-app="FDAApp" ng-controller="formController">
    // D3 directives
</body>
// external scripts inclusion (angular.js, d3.js, topojson.js etc)

// app-controller.js contains the ng-app and ng-controllers
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/app-controller.js"></script>

// Here I want to introduce conditional inclusion of either factory-splunk.js or factory-elastic.js based on initial dialog popup
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/factory/factory-splunk.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/factory/factory-elastic.js"></script>-->

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dataServerpopUpDiv").dialog();
        $("#dataServer").val("");
        $('#dataServer').on('change', '', function (e) {
            $('#dataServerpopUpDiv').dialog('close');
            if($("#dataServer").val()=="splunk")
                $.getScript("js/factory/factory-splunk.js");
            else if($("#dataServer").val()=="elastic")
                $.getScript("js/factory/factory-elastic.js");
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="dataServerpopUpDiv" title="Select Data Source">
    <select id="dataServer">
        <option value="Splunk">Splunk</option>
        <option value="Elastic">Elastic</option>
    </select>
</div>


</html>
```

The signature of `app-controller.js` is shown below. Notice that the `DataService object` is used here which is provided by the `factory-xxx.js` :

```
    var app = angular.module('FDAApp', []);

    app.controller('formController', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache, $interval, $timeout, DataService) {
      DataService.initService();
    }
```

The signature of `factory-xxx.js` is;

```
angular.module('FDAApp').factory('DataService', function($http) {
}
```

What I am trying here:
I want to provide user the selection dialog among the two options, based on which the appropriate factory will be loaded.

Problem:
Jquery dialog being `asyncronous`, the `DataService` object is uninitialized and method call `DataService.initService()` does not happen.

Is there any alternative way of including scripts and controlling the sequence of their loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-app` makes Angular to automatically bootstrap the app once DOM has loaded.

From Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization):

> You should call `angular.bootstrap()` *after* you've loaded or defined your modules. You cannot add controllers, services, directives, etc after an application bootstraps.

And so, you can, if you wish, load the `.js` files that constitute an Angular modules conditionally, but then you have to call `angular.bootstrap()` manually (and remove `ng-app`):

```
// after choice is made
if($("#dataServer").val()=="splunk")
     $.getScript("js/factory/controller-splunk.js", bootstrapAngular);
else if($("#dataServer").val()=="elastic")
     $.getScript("js/factory/controller-elastic.js", bootstrapAngular);
```

```
function bootstrapAngular(){
   angular.bootstrap(document, ["FDAApp"]);
}
```

**Off-topic:**

I would also strongly suggest adhering to one-module-per-file best practice to avoid issues with script loading order. So, define a new dependent module in your `controller-splunk.js`/`controller-elastic.js` files:

```
angular.module("someName", []);
```

and have the app module `FDAApp` depend on it:

```
angular.module("FDAApp", ["someName"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery in your project you can use it's Promise/Deferred helpers to manage your scripts execution order.

```
function loadDialog () {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  //I'm not sure which dialog plugin are you using
  //so I consider first argument as callback of your dialog
  $("#dataServerpopUpDiv").dialog(function () {
    dfd.resolve();
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}

$.when(loadDialog()).
  then(function () {
    //do what ever you need here
    //you can continue to chain more that one then
    //and they will be executed one after the other
  });
```

to understand it better you can read: 
https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/